# TFS building Resx file is using higher .NET Framework version

Tags: .net, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have compiled a class library that uses v.2.0 `System.Drawing` and it is used in an ASP.NET v3.5 web site.

When I compile the class library using Visual Studio 2010, I can use the DLL in my site without errors.

When I remotely compile the class library using TFS2010, I get an exception when the call for `System.Drawing` occurs.

**Exception**

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0 ...
```

I think the trouble area is regarding the resources I'm using. I have used added a resource file (resx) and added an image. My code is pulling the image through the resource classes that are generated for me. The generated code is converting the resource to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

Anyone seen this before? Anyone know how to make it stop using .NET 4? On all the references to System.Drawing, I set property "SpecificVersion" to true.

Answer (score 0):

Does the build server have .net 3.5 installed on it?

If you're using a Windows Server 2008R2 machine then it doesn't have these on by default.  You have to add the "feature" through Administrative Tools->Server Manager->Features.